# How to count number of combinations in python?

Tags: python, pandas

In this dataset:
[image]

I want to count number of matches between two teams.

Is there any tool in python for this?

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: [Please don't post images of data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Pandas has functionality to compare columns with a given value (string here), combine them with logical operators and count the number of rows with the desired result. If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here with your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to count combinations independently of order, you can aggregate as [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) and use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df[['home_team', 'away_team']].apply(frozenset, axis=1).value_counts()
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'home_team': list('ABCABC'), 'away_team': list('BAABCA')})

# output
(A, B)    3
(A, C)    2
(B, C)    1
dtype: int64
```

Alternative using [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
# count one-way
out = pd.crosstab(df['home_team'], df['away_team'])
# add other way
out = out.add(out.T, fill_value=0)
out.rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
```

example output:

```
   A  B  C
A  0  3  2
B  3  0  1
C  2  1  0
```